# Yeoman Yo-emi generator workflow install failing

Tags: wordpress, macos, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Im trying to run this wordpress generator: https://github.com/zoerooney/yo-emi I have yeoman, grunt, bower and gulp.js installed and running. When I try to run the generator with `$ yo-emi`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../util/art'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-emi/app/index.js:7:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

After a lot of debugging, I still can't get it to work properly. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the repository. Seems to be resolved.